# Combine new disk with disk C

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

My primary disk (C) is full and I would like to add storage to C disk so I bought the new SSD. After that, I want to combine these primary C disks with new disk.

How to do it? I have been looking for that one but am still unlucky and I can't find the similar solution to my scenario.

How can I combine these two disks with tools?

Comment: A disk span. A bad idea. Better to move/install OS on largest of the two.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen, Is there any way to do that? e.g. clone the primary and paste to largest one and make it a bootable disk. without tools? looks like now I have to buy extra tool to do it.

Comment: @Iwin - Disk Cloners exist, it’s a product, not a tool though

Comment: Two choices.   Add a disk and use it as an overflow disk.  Better: get a bigger drive and put everything on one drive.  Your idea (disk span) will not work.

Comment: What OS are we talking about ?

Comment: @John Okay thanks. I will follow the better way.

Comment: @RohitGupta Window 11

Comment: Some (most?) SSD vendors provide free tools for data migration; personally I've used Samsung Data Migration software and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Another option is to simply point directories like Documents, Music, Video or Pictures to the new external drive. A lot less hassle than installing on a new drive, IMO. Windows provides the tools.

Answer (score 2):

Although it looks like it is possible to unite 2 physical disks into a common partition, as Rohit pointed it out, I wouldn't do it. If the original issue was the lack of storage space, why not simply replace the old one by a larger one, and doing a backup/restore using Ghost or alike. This works, and is enough to solve the issue.

Disk span might be the only solution in case you filled up an already huge disk that can't be replaced by a larger one (or it would be too expensive). Then, this kind of solution would be justified, as well as building a RAID system.

On the other hand, your first disk should be probably enough to store system files (windows, user and appdata folders), just put anything else (downloaded stuff) on the new one, and put any new installs on the new (say D: disk) as well. Those system folders will very unlikely go over a few dozens of Gb so even with a 200Gb disk should make it. (Just put all personal stuff from Documents, Desktop etc. to D: If you have some huge installs in "Program files" for ex. that eats up the most space you can also migrate them to D or just reinstall them there. All of this is not a big deal to realise.

A general advice: always go for the easyest and most standard solution. All others bring up extra risks in case of data corruption - say from power failure or malware, that average rescue techniques would not overcome.

Imagine: ONLY the OS that implemented the "disk span" would be aware of it. In case you cannot boot, any outside recovery tool would see just 2 separate drives with corrupt partitions. Any system or even data recovery would be a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

Note I haven't done this myself.  Instructions abbreviated from [windowscentral](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-one-large-volume-using-multiple-hard-drives-windows-10) for Windows 10, but will probably work for Win11.

> **How to combine multiple hard drives into one large volume**
> It's important to note that you will erase the content of the hard drives participating of the Spanned or Striped volume, as such make sure to backup the data before proceeding.
>
> 1. Use the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>  shortcut to open the Power User menu and select Disk Management.
> 2. Right-click the hard drive volume and select Delete volume.
> 3. Repeat for 2nd drive volume.
> 4. Right-click the unallocated space of the drive and select New Spanned Volume.
> 5. Click Next.
> 6. Select the additional disks, one by one, and click Add.
> 7. Click Next.
> 8. Leave the default drive letter assignment and click Next.
> 9. Make sure the file system is set to NTFS, allocation unit size is set to default, and choose a volume label.
> 10. Check the Perform a quick format option.
> 11. Click Next.
> 12. Click Finish.

---

**Above involves deleting your existing drive contents.  And if one drive fails, it could potentially destroy the whole spanned drive.**

If you are running out of space then my suggestion would be to migrate folders out of drive C onto the new drive using Symlinks using Windows command **mklink**.

> Syntax
>
> **mklink [[/d] | [/h] | [/j]]**
>
> /d Creates a directory symbolic link. By default, this command creates a file symbolic link.
>
> /h Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
>
> /j Creates a Directory Junction.
>
> <link>   Specifies the name of the symbolic link being created.
>
> <target> Specifies the path (relative or absolute) that the new symbolic link refers to.
>
> /? Displays help at the command prompt.

I have used this to move some folders out of C drive onto other drives, such as Thunderbirds email storage.  I haven't tried it with system folders, but it should work.

Comment: Disk spans are a bad idea and should be avoided and not recommended IMO.

Comment: You said that earlier, and I have suggested not to use them.  However, I have answered the question as asked.  Why do you think they are a bad idea ?

Comment: Because if 1 of the drives in a span fails you usually lose ALL the data.  Further more it increase the complexity of recovery and the cost if you need to send any of the drives in to a data recovery service.